# How to set value for autoanswer in apt-get install

Tags: 16.04, apt, xorg

I'm trying to install `xorg` on my Ubuntu Docker image. Usually I use below syntax:

```
RUN apt-get install -y <application>
```

to answer `"Yes"` forcibly on "Yes/No" dialogs, but when I use

```
RUN apt-get install -y xorg
```

I got a dialog like

> The layout of keyboards varies per country, with some countries having
>   multiple common layouts. Please select the country of origin for the
>   keyboard of this computer.
>
> 1. Afghani
> 2. Albanian
> 3. Amharic
> 4. Arabic
> 5. Arabic (Morocco)
> 6. Arabic (Syria) 
>      ...

So how can I autoselect, for example, value `"29. English (US)"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andersson was able to solve the issue using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165407/installing-lightdm-in-dockerfile-raises-interactive-keyboard-layout-menu/38850571#38850571).

> 1. Copy a working /etc/default/keyboard file to the directory that contains the Dockerfile.
> 2. Add the following line to your Dockerfile before installing xdm or lightdm.
>
>    ```
>    COPY ./keyboard /etc/default/keyboard
>    ```
>
> Example keyboard file:
>
> ```
> # Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
> # documentation on what to do after having modified this file.
>
> # The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
> # values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
> # in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
>
> XKBMODEL="pc105"
> XKBLAYOUT="us"
> XKBVARIANT="intl"
> XKBOPTIONS=""
>
> # If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
> # specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
> # before /usr is mounted.
> # KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
> BACKSPACE="guess"
> ```